# Examples for a conjecture of Beilinson

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

Beilinson has conjectured that for a regular, complete, geometrically irreducible curve $C$ of genus $g$ over a number field $k$, $rank(K_2(C))=g[k:\mathbb{Q}]$. As far as I know it is not known in the general case whether $rank(K_2(C))\geq g[k:\mathbb{Q}]$ or not. I'm looking for examples of smooth projective planar curves of genus $g\geq 3$ over $k$, which is known there are at least $g[k:\mathbb{Q}]$ independent elements in the second algebraic $K$-group. (In particular the curve isn't hyper-elliptic)

Comment: Quite a lot is known about Fermat curves; the paper of Otsubo "On the regulator of Fermat motives and generalized hypergeometric functions" might be a useful place to start.

Comment: Modular curves $X_1(N) / \mathbf{Q}$ are another natural thing to try: the $K_2$ of these curves is rather well understood thanks to Bloch, Beilinson and Kato.

Comment: Rob de Jeu and Hang Liu have a paper 'On K_2 of certain families of curves', International Mathematics Research Notices, 2015 (2015), issue 21, 10929-10958, https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.4822. They give examples of the type that you are looking for, I believe.